# Swift - Type 'any Protocol' cannot conform to 'Protocol'

Tags: swift

I'm having this compilation error and I don't really know what's the best way to solve it.

In this basic exemple, the error says `Type 'any Leg' cannot conform to 'Leg'` .

I've tried to mirror the same hierarchy that I have in my project, but I just couldn't come up with something better at the moment (it's not about dogs obviously).

```
protocol Animal { 
    var legs: [Leg] { get }
}

class Dog: Animal {
    var legs: [Leg] = []
}

protocol Leg {} 

protocol ZoneOfBody {} 

extension Array: ZoneOfBody where Element: Leg {}

func test() -> ZoneOfBody {
    let dog = Dog()
    return dog.legs // <---- The compilation error is here
}
```

What possibilities do I have ? Thanks in advance

Comment: A protocol cannot conform to a protocol. What is the code supposed to do? What is `legs` in `test` supposed to be. `Leg` and `ZoneOfBody` do nothing. It seems that you are going to abstract your code to death. At some point the type represented by a protocol must be a concrete static type.

Comment: The app has a modular architecture and most of the protocols needed here are in a shared module. The concrete implementations are in the main module though. And why do you say a protocol cannot conform to a protocol ? You can have a protocol that conforms to Equatable for example ?

Comment: I mean a protocol cannot conform to itself.

Comment: This was previously closed as a duplicate, but the answer given on the linked question was quite complex and involved and doesn't directly answer this question. So I reopened it and posted an answer that fixes this particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocols cannot conform to themselves and `dog.legs` refers to an array of a protocol which  cannot meet the requirement that the return type conform to `Leg`, which may seem bizarre but there are good reasons.

To fix this, the `legs` property of `Dog` must be an array of a concrete type. Also, the type in the protocol needs to be an associated type (or `Dog` won't conform).

The following code is what you need.

```
protocol Animal {
    associatedtype L: Leg // Associated type
    var legs: [L]{ get set }
}

struct DogLeg: Leg {} // Concrete type conforming to Leg

class Dog: Animal {
    var legs: [DogLeg] = [] // This now meets the protocol requirement
}

protocol Leg {}

protocol ZoneOfBody {}

extension Array: ZoneOfBody where Element: Leg {}

func test() -> ZoneOfBody {
    let dog = Dog()
    return dog.legs // Now compiles
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! Indeed it fixes the issue. However I'm getting a new error now : `Use of protocol 'Animal' as a type must be written 'any Animal'` everywhere this protocol is used (as a method parameter for example). And since this protocol is used almost everywhere in the app, I was wondering if there was a way to avoid this ?

Comment: @Xys that's a new diagnostic introduced in recent versions of Swift. There's no way around it except to insert `any` as stated. It was introduced because people keep confusing protocols with types.